# sensors reporting weird temperatures

Tags: temperature, sensors

`lm-sensors` is reporting weird temps for me:

```
$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:      +38.0°C  (high = +72.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)  

coretemp-isa-0001
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 1:      +35.0°C  (high = +72.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)  

coretemp-isa-0002
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 2:      +32.0°C  (high = +72.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)  

coretemp-isa-0003
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 3:      +42.0°C  (high = +72.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)  

w83627dhg-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
Vcore:       +1.10 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)   
in1:         +1.62 V  (min =  +0.06 V, max =  +0.17 V)   ALARM
AVCC:        +3.34 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)   
VCC:         +3.34 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)   
in4:         +1.83 V  (min =  +1.30 V, max =  +1.15 V)   ALARM
in5:         +1.26 V  (min =  +0.83 V, max =  +1.03 V)   ALARM
in6:         +0.11 V  (min =  +1.22 V, max =  +0.56 V)   ALARM
3VSB:        +3.30 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)   
Vbat:        +3.18 V  (min =  +2.70 V, max =  +3.30 V)   
fan1:          0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, div = 128)  ALARM
fan2:       1117 RPM  (min =  860 RPM, div = 8)
fan3:          0 RPM  (min = 10546 RPM, div = 128)  ALARM
fan4:          0 RPM  (min = 10546 RPM, div = 128)  ALARM
fan5:          0 RPM  (min = 10546 RPM, div = 128)  ALARM
temp1:       +88.0°C  (high = +20.0°C, hyst =  +4.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = diode
temp2:       +25.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = diode
temp3:      +121.5°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = thermistor
cpu0_vid:   +2.050 V
```

Please note `temp3`. How can I know what `temp3` is, and why it is so high? The system is really stable (which I guess it wouldn't be at those temps). Also, note the really decent core temps, which suggest a healthy system as well.

My guess is that the readout is wrong. On another computer it reported temperatures below 0 degrees centigrade, which was not possible, considering the environment temperature of ~22-24.

Is this some known bug/issue? Should I try some Windows programs (like CPU-Z) and see they give similar results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your hardware the sensors on your motherboard need additional calibration. Unfortunately the standard values given in `/etc/sensors.conf` and in `/etc/sensors3.conf` can only give you rough estimates because of variations in your hardware.

However there is nothing that can't be set up. There are many self-explanatory notes in the sensors.conf file and you will also find additional information in `man sensors.conf` on how to do this.

If your really need precise values there is no way other than taking a thermometer and measure yourself for setting up the calibration. This can take hours as you need to measure at different temperatures. Such precise values are not really needed for a normal hardware setup. If you feel like overclocking then maybe you need at least calibrate the upper limits to avoid hardware damage.

If you use the lm-sensors panel applet then you also have access to a GUI to ease calibration.

Answer (score 0):

You either have to follow the traces on the motherboard and have a reference datasheet for the chipset, or you have to make an educated guess.  In your case I would say temp3 is almost certainly just not connected to a sensor and so it always reads at max temp.