# Is there a Temparature monitor application for Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: software-recommendation, sensors, tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get sensor readings for recent hardware?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22242/how-to-get-sensor-readings-for-recent-hardware)

On Windows 7 I have got Asus Probe, which came with my ASUS P5QPL-AM Motherboard Drivers DVD. It monitors disk speed, fan speed, Processor Temperature etc.

Is there such a alternative on Ubuntu 11.10 ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/53762/how-to-use-to-use-lm-sensors

Comment: @Uri Herra: What are CONS of using LM Sencors ? Does it have any bad effect on hardware ? Will it work on Ubuntu 11.10 Unity Desktop ?

Comment: Other than sometimes confusing you as you may not know which sensor you're watching, none it's a monitoring tool nothing else.

Comment: @Uri: You should have posted it as an answer. Ok neways thanks. I have answered my own question. Hope this will clear things to someone.

Comment: Not really, I wouldn't say it was a full answer, It was a merely a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can simply do this by installing "Xsensors":

http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xsensors

[image]

This application will install "lm-sensors". If the addon is not selected there, you need to select it.

After you install xsensors, you need to configure lm-sensors.

To do so, open Terminal and run:

```
 sudo sensors-detect
```

just press ENTER for everything it suggests. Lastly it will show whether to add what it finds to /etc/modules. Hit Enter again and you are done.

Now open Dash and search for xsensors.

Answer (score 2):

There is an app indicator that shows it on the top panel:

Application Indicator showing hardware sensors.

[image: sensors]

**For 11.10:**

First add the repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:alexmurray/indicator-sensors
```

Update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And then install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-sensors
```

Then run `indicator-sensors`

**For 12.04:**

This command should download from launchpad and install it for you:

```
cd /tmp ; a=$(uname -p) ; if [[ "$a" = "x86_64" ]] ; then wget https://launchpad.net/~alexmurray/+archive/indicator-sensors/+files/indicator-sensors_0.1-1_amd64.deb ; else https://launchpad.net/~alexmurray/+archive/indicator-sensors/+files/indicator-sensors_0.1-1_i386.deb ; fi ; chmod +x /tmp/indicator-sensors_0.1-1* ; sudo dpkg -i /tmp/indicator-sensors_0.1-1*
```

Comment: @ Desgua: It says no Active sensors !

Comment: Go to preferences and select the sensors you want.