# Is 45 deg C too high for cpu temp?

Tags: cpu, temperature

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 on Sony Vaio Intel i7 quad core. I have a cpu temp of about 45 deg C. When I used Windows 7, the temp was about 30 deg C. Is 45 normal for Ubuntu?

Edit:
More specifically: Intel® Core™ i7 CPU M 640 @ 2.80GHz × 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are are not specifying which model of cpu you are running, there are multiple i7 processors. For Sandy Bridge the maximum temperature is 100degrees C., so, you are well inside the parameters. [Here](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-Core-i7-2677M-Notebook-Processor.57418.0.html) you can
you can browse some charts.

Comment: The model is Intel® Core™ i7 CPU M 640 @ 2.80GHz × 4

Comment: For your particular processor the temp threshold is even bigger: 105deg C. From intel specs: http://ark.intel.com/products/49666

Comment: Thanks for the info, but my question is what is the normal cpu temperature when running ubuntu, not the max temp.

Comment: @function: there is no "normal" CPU temperature. This mainly depends on your individual settings. Also the temperature reported by sensors is far from reality when not calibrated. See this question: http://askubuntu.com/q/21381/3940 on how to calibrate sensors (you could even make your sensors display 10°C).

Comment: sorry, I was just surprised that the cpu temp in Ubuntu is much higher than in Windows

Comment: @functionptr - If your laptop also has a dedicated GPU, that could be the source of the extra heat.